# Should I use another random variable for the sum, if I work with random vectors?

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution

Assume I have a simple random vector $(X, Y)$ with common distribution $P((0, 0))=1/6, P((1, 1))=1/6, P((3, 1))=1/4, P((0, 2))=1/6, P((1, 2))=1/4$, all others are zero.

If I would like to argue about $P(X+Y=k)$: Should I define a new random variable $Z(X, Y)=X+Y$ and talk about $P_Z$? E.g. $P(X+Y=0)=1/6$ or is it more precise to say $P_Z(0)=1/6$?

**Edit @Tim**: Assume you throw two coins. Then the probability space $\Omega=\{0, 1\}\times \{0, 1\}$ with Probability $P_i=0.5$. If you want to find the distribution you define the random variable $X=i+j$ where $(i,j)\in \Omega$. Then, the probability for throwing two times head is $P_X(x=2)=P(X(\omega)=x=2)$. Without random variables you can't discribe the experiment. How about the situation above? What does $P(X+Y=k)$ mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, but it is your choice what notation and symbols you'll use.

Comment: @Tim So you would say, both point of views are correct? I thought $P(X+Y=k)$ is not really defined, but maybe I missed something...

Comment: "You throw two coins simultaneously and get two heads, what is the probability of observing such event?" -- what is not defined in here?

Comment: @Tim See my edit. Too long for a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function of a random variable(s) is a random variable. When you see $P(X+Y=k)=q$, it means

$$
Z=X+Y \\
P(Z=k)=q
$$

but there is no need to name the intermediate variable. If you wish you can name it, sometimes it could improve readability, but you don't have to.

[Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is an example of such variable. It is defined as a sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables:

$$\begin{align}
X_i &\stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Bernoulli}(p) \\
Y &= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \\
Y &\sim \mathsf{Binomial}(n,p)
\end{align}$$

and, as well, you can write something like:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Binomial}(n,p)
$$